# Push and pop in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-router

I am new in react native , i  have create several screens in react native. but i am facing problem in navigating between pages.

1. We have to manage the stack and stack index with own ??
2. Without defining the Route  in `Apps.js` can we navigate to other pages ??

I followed these tutorials but didn't get simple ways to navigate through pages .

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/

As in ios we write

Jump to new pages :
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

Back to previous pages :
 `[self.navigationController popViewController animated:YES];`

*(pushing controller to stack and pop controller from stack is managed by UINavigationController it self )*

My Question is :

1.What  is the easiest or Proper way to implement the navigation in react native ?.

2. How can we Set Animated property like in ios ?

Please help me , thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The most popular way of implementing navigation is by using [React-Navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation).
2. You need to explain how is it in iOS. If you need to perform animation on the component, screen or navigaiton, you use [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) library or [Layout Animation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html) of React-Native.